# Espresso RecyclerView scrollTo throwing AppNotIdleException

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso, recyclerview-layout

I'm trying to test a RecyclerView using Espresso's framework and currently hitting into the following issue -

Espresso's method

```
    fun scrollToItemAndCheck() {
         onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
              .perform(scrollTo<RecyclerView.ViewHolder(hasDescendant(withText("item text"))))
}
```

RecyclerView -

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

**Issue** - `scrollToItemAndCheck()` throws an AppNotIdleException.

***Note - The same method starts working fine when I wrap the `RecyclerView` inside a `FrameLayout`***

```
<FrameLayout>
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Any clue as to what's going on?

Comment: When are you calling `scrollToItemAndCheck()`?  The RecyclerView may be binding views, have you tried calling it after the recyclerview has fully loaded?

Comment: Yes! Calling it after the recyclerView has fully loaded!